# Specific comparison of two arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

There are many symbol games working in this way so this should sound familiar to you.

**Facts:**

1. I have two arrays with same length of 4.
   (A[4] and B[4])
2. I fill them with random integers from 1 to 6.
3. I can NOT sort them in any way (they must stay the same).

**Problems:**

I need to compare them and after that I need to have 3 values. FIRST one needs to count how many elements are the same and in the same place. I do it like this and it is working:

```
int first = 0;
int k = 0;
for (int j=1; j<=4; j++)
{
k++;
if (A[k] == B[j])
   {
    first++;            
   }
}
```

SECOND one needs to count how many elements are the same BUT not at the same place. THIRD one needs to count how many elements are not the same at all.

I need a solution to count either SECOND or THIRD number, because after that I can just subtract like `4-(first+second)` or `4-(first+second)`.

Comment: Your first solution is wrong. You need to have a nested loop that runs for each element on the first array on all the elements on the second array. Another thing, arrays are *zero-base*, your loop should begin from 0 to 3.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Apart from the index, the first solution is correct.

Comment: Yes, first solution is correct, except index `j` should start with 0.

Comment: Is this for some algorithm puzzle? Because your suggestion runs in O(n^2)

Comment: `I need a solution to count either...`. And what have you tried?

Comment: @jlordo He says that the length is 4, doesn't he need to begin from 0 to 3?

Comment: The homework tag is obsolete i think. Read the tag wiki.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Yes, I said you are right, regarding the index. But he does **not** need a nested loop (for the `first` problem)....

Comment: @jlordo Oh... my mistake :) Thanks for the correction. (I didn't notice the **same place**).

Comment: @SJuan76: I tried few algorithms but they were not working well so I didn't post them.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I know arrays are zero-base, but I did this intentionally because of some others calculations. And they are short arrays so optimizations is not a problem here ;)

Comment: Instead of editing a "solution" into your question, you should post it as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Eventually I made the right algorithm. In general, the solution is to keep track of what fields you used when counting FIRST value. And here is the code:

```
int first = 0;
int second = 0;
int third = 0;

boolean[] codeUsed = new boolean[4];
boolean[] guessUsed = new boolean[4];

//same value and same place
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
    {
       if (A[i] == B[i]) 
       {
          first++;
          codeUsed[i] = guessUsed[i] = true;
       }
    }

//same value but not right place
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
   {
   for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
      {
      if (!codeUsed[i] && !guessUsed[j] && A[i] == B[j])
         {
            second++;
            codeUsed[i] = guessUsed[j] = true;
            break;
         }
       }
    }

//not the same value
third = 4 - first - second;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the logic you should use: loop over the first array; for each element, check if the corresponding element of the second array is the same - if yes, increment your `first` counter.  If they are not the same, then check whether the second array contains the corresponding element of the first array.  If it does, then it's definitely not in the same position (you just checked same positions) - increment your `second` count.  Otherwise, increment your `third` count.  The code can be as following:

```
int[] A = {...};
int[] B = {...};

List<Integer> lstB = new ArrayList<Integer>(B.length);
for (int index = 0; index < B.length; index++) {
    lstB.add(B[index]);
}

int first = 0, second = 0, third = 0;

for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    if(A[i] == B[i]) {
        first++;
    }
    else if(lstB.contains(A[i]) {
        second++;
    }
    else {
        third++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this will not work as you expect, due to the use of `int[]` instead of `Integer[]`. Your `lstB` will have the size 1, no matter what length `B` is.

Comment: @jlordo yes, I see that.  I'll change the answer in a sec

Comment: This is not working. Check the algorithm for example for A{1,4,4,4} and B{5,4,1,1}.